# Prevent Bash from removing zero-bytes in double-quoted string?

Tags: linux, bash, c

I need to supply arbitrary bytes for an `argv` argument of a C program.

However, if the bytes are put within double-quotes, the zero-bytes are removed as can be seen below:

```
v="$(python -c 'import sys; sys.stdout.write("ABC\x18\x10\x00\x00\x10")')"
echo -n $v | hexdump -C
00000000  41 42 43 18 10 10                                 |ABC...|
00000006
```

Indeed, the double-quotes remove the zero-bytes, since `hexdump` shows them in its output:

```
python -c 'import sys; sys.stdout.write("ABC\x18\x10\x00\x00\x10")' | hexdump -C
00000000  41 42 43 18 10 00 00 10                           |ABC.....|
00000008
```

How can I supply these arbitrary bytes as program arguments?

Answer (score 3):

> I need to supply arbitrary bytes for an argv argument of a C program.

You cannot do that. The argv arguments are, by definition, zero-terminated strings, so they cannot contain any NUL byte. You'll have to pass the data to your program via a pipe, file, shared memory, etc, or do some escaping and unescaping.

Even if `bash` was supporting NUL-bytes in its strings (as `zsh`, `perl` or `python` do), there would be no way to pass those strings to other programs via command line arguments or environment variables.

Comment: What escaping could be done?

Comment: For instance, I have a C program where the user can specify via the command line the address of an abstract unix socket. Since such an adress starts with a NUL byte and can contain other NUL bytes, I use the convention that a `@` means a null byte, and a backslash escapes the next char, so `\@` for a literal `@`. That's very easy to reverse *in place*. You can come with your own convention -- for instance, treat binary data as iso-8859-1 and translate it to [modified utf-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Modified_UTF-8), where the null byte is encoded as `\xc0\x80` ;-)